# How to get count for continuously repeating values in continuous arrays in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array and I want count for continuously repeating values.But it is not giving what I want.I have explained with an example what my needs are.So please help me out in this if you have any idea about how to solve this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 44
                [1] => 1132
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 27
                [1] => 28
                [2] => 32
                [3] => 37
                [4] => 38
                [5] => 114
                [6] => 117
                [7] => 273
                [8] => 1132
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 27
                [1] => 28
                [2] => 32
                [3] => 34
                [4] => 36
                [5] => 37
                [6] => 38
                [7] => 44
                [8] => 114
                [9] => 117
                [10] => 273
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 27
                [1] => 28
                [2] => 32
                [3] => 34
                [4] => 36
                [5] => 37
                [6] => 38
                [7] => 44
                [8] => 114
                [9] => 117
                [10] => 273
            )
    )
```

I want result like:

```
    array
    (
        [44]=>1
        [1132]=>2
        [27]=>3
        [28]=>3
        [32]=>3
    ........
        [273]=>2
        [1132]=>1
    )
```

I did this way but its not giving the result I want.. And it can also be user defined. If user enters number "3", the values which are continuously repeating 3 or more times should come.

```
$s=array();
for($k=0;$k<count($absentNoArray);$k++)
{
    for($p=0;$p<count($absentNoArray[$k]);$p++)
    {
        $temp=$absentNoArray[$k][$p];
        $count=1;
        for($l=$k+1;$l<count($absentNoArray);$l++)
        {           
            for($q=0;$q<count($absentNoArray[$l]);$q++)
            {
                if($temp==$absentNoArray[$l][$q])
                {
                    $count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;  
                }               
            }
        }
        $s[]=$count;
    }   
}
print_r($s);
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: `I did this way but its giving the result I want..` So is it working or not?

Comment: how much recursion is possible?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do...

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: sorry its not working..

Comment: Is there some type of logic behind this formula you've devised?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you use a smaller data set as an example? Based on the data, I can't see any reason for 44 to be 1 and 1132 to be 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuosly repeating?"

Comment: @serakfalcon: It means 44 is in first array only (continuously) so [44]=>1, 1132 is in first and second both but not in third, so it is has no repeatation further in third so count for it [1132]=>2. Like this..

Comment: @user3740116 but 44 is in the third and fourth arrays, should it have a count of 2?

Comment: I agree with @serakfalcon. Your question does not make sense. In your desired output you have two elements with the key `1132`. Not only is this illogical with what you're describing, it is also not valid to have two matching keys in an array.

Comment: @serakfalcon: yes 44 should have a count of 2.

Comment: Why 2? 44 shows up 3 times. `array[0][0], array[2][7], array[3][7]`. 273 also shows up 3 times but you have 2...

Comment: I think the goal is to count consecutive instances, so the first instance wouldn't be counted.

Comment: Arre i want continuous count. First count for 44 is 1. afterwards if 44 comes once than count 1 again. Again if 44 comes but continuously twice than count 2 for 44.

Comment: @BrandonGano: No first one would also be counted but as 1 if comes once.

Comment: But it would later be replaced by 2, correct? Or do you want two entries for 44? (As stated earlier in the comments, duplicate keys are not allowed in arrays.)

Comment: @BrandonGano: ohh ohk.. Than can we get it on user defined values? Means if user enters number "3", the values which are continuously repeating 3 or more times should come.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$myArray = []; //This is your Array
$combinedArr = [];

foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    array_push($combinedArr, $item);
}

$quantityArray = array_count_values($combinedArr);
print_r($quantityArray)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Yup this is the exact answer I was thinking, but it doesn't match with the OPs desired output. Good answer, but the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a straight count of different values in the arrays, for any level of recursion:

```
function array_val_counter($input) {
    $response = array();
    if (is_array($input)) {
        array_walk($input,function($value,$key) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $recursiveresponse = array_val_counter($value);
                foreach($recursiveresponse as $recurval => $count) {
                    if (isset($response[$recurval])) {
                        $response[$recurval]+=$count;
                    } else {
                        $response[$recurval]=$count;
                    }
                }
            } elseif (isset($response[$value])) {
                $response[$value]++;
            } else {
                $response[$value] = 1;
            }
        });
    } else {
       //input is not an array, do some error
    }
    return $response;
}
```

EDIT: for a count of numbers in sequence:

```
function array_val_in_seq($input) {
    $result = array();
    $numarrays = count($input);
    for($i=0;$<$numarrays;$i++) {
        switch($i) {
            case 0:
                 //for the first array, add every value to the results
                 //and go through the remaining arrays, stopping if the result is not found
                 //store how far it got before stopping (aka consecutive count)
                 foreach($input[0] as $arrayval) {
                     for($y=1;$y<$numarrays;$y++) {
                         $result[$arrayval] = 1;
                         if(in_array($arrayval,$input[$y])) {
                             $result[$arrayval] = $y+1;
                         } else {
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 break;
           case $numarrays:
                //for the last  array, give any elements that do not already exist
                // a count of 1
                foreach($input[$numarrays] as $arrayval) {
                    if(array_key_exists($arrayval,$result) === false) {
                        $result[$arrayval] = 1;
                    }
                }
                break;
           default:
               //if the array value doesn't exist in the previous array (not consecutive) go through the remaining arrays, stopping if the value isn't found.
              //if the number is larger than what already exists, replace it.
               foreach($input[$i] as $arrayval) {
                   if(!in_array($arrayval,$input[$i-1])) {
                       for($y=$i+1;$y<$numarrays;$y++) {
                           if(in_array($arrayval,$input[$y])) {
                               $count = $y - $i + 1;
                               if (!isset($result[$arrayval] ||
                                 (isset($result[$arrayval]) && $result[$arrayval] > $count)) {
                                    $result[$arrayval] =$count;
                               }
                           } else {
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   } 
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the straight count,actually the need is for continuous count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this performs, but it works for me:

```
function countConsecutiveValues($arrays, $minCount = 1) {
  // Merge all values into a single array
  $values = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrays), SORT_REGULAR);
  $counts = array();
  // Loop through each value
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $count = 0;
    $counts[$value] = 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
      if (array_search($value, $array)) {
        // If the current array contains the value, increment the counter
        $count++;
      }
      else {
        // If the current array does not contain the value, update the counts
        // array (if necessary) and reset the counter
        if ($count >= $minCount) {
          $counts[$value] = max($counts[$value], $count);
        }
        $count = 0;
      }
    }
    // Get the final count after the last array is processed
    if ($count >= $minCount) {
      $counts[$value] = max($counts[$value], $count);
    }
  }
  // This should remove any zero counts before returning
  return array_filter($counts);
}
```

When used like this:

```
$arrays = array(
  array(44, 1132),
  array(27, 28, 32, 37, 38, 114, 117, 273, 1132),
  array(27, 28, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 44, 114, 117, 273),
  array(27, 28, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 44, 114, 117, 273)
);

print_r(countConsecutiveValues($arrays, 3));
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [27] => 3 [28] => 3 [32] => 3 [37] => 3 [38] => 3 [114] => 3 [117] => 3 [273] => 3 )
```

Comment: heya thanx.. I too got solution. Anyways thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer but thank you to all for your efforts.

```
$userValue=4;
$idCount=array();
$s=array();
$status=0;
for($k=0;$k<count($absentNoArray);$k++)
{
    for($p=0;$p<count($absentNoArray[$k]);$p++)
    {
        $temp=$absentNoArray[$k][$p];
        $count=1;
        for($l=$k+1;$l<count($absentNoArray);$l++)
        {           
            foreach($absentNoArray[$l] as $key=>$val)
            {
                if($temp==$val)
                {                   
                    $count++;
                    $status=1;
                }       
            }
            if($status==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if($count<$userValue)
                {
                    $status=0;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!in_array($temp,$s))
                    {
                        $s[]=$temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }       
}
print_r($s);
```